# removeIf() method. removes all the elements from the List

Tags: java, predicate

I have a list of user, i want to delete from my list the user with an id < 3

Actually i do this:

```
[...]
int pid1 = 1;
int pid2 = 2;
int pid3 = 3;
Predicate<Person> personPredicate1 = p-> p.getPid() == pid1;
Predicate<Person> personPredicate2 = p-> p.getPid() == pid2;
Predicate<Person> personPredicate3 = p-> p.getPid() == pid3;
list.removeIf(personPredicate1);
list.removeIf(personPredicate2);
list.removeIf(personPredicate3);
[...]
```

I think I do not use the right method?

Comment: How did you create the List ? share the line of code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a single `removeIf`:

```
list.removeIf(p -> p.getPid() < 3);
```

EDIT:

Based on the error you posted, you are trying to remove elements from an immutable collection, which is not possible.

You can create a copy of the original `List` and remove elements from the copy:

```
List<Person> copy = new ArrayList<>(list);
copy.removeIf(p -> p.getPid() < 3);
```

Comment: I have this error :`2019-01-07 11:54:09.931 ERROR 171920 --- [  XNIO-4 task-3] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTrait: Not Implemented
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.removeIf(Collections.java:1084)`

Comment: @Mercer You are trying to remove an element from an unmodifiable collection, which is why it fails.

Comment: or create a stream directly from the unmodifiable collection and use `filter`. `list.stream().filter(p -> p.getPid() >= 3).collect(toList());`

Answer (score 1):

You may call the method only once:

- without intermediate variable

  ```
  list.removeIf(p -> p.getPid() < 3);
  ```
- with intermediate variable

  ```
  Predicate<Person> predicate = p-> p.getPid() < 3;
  list.removeIf(predicate);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you can do using Project Reactor:

```
Flux.from(list).filter(a -> a.getId() > 3).collectList();  //retuns Mono<List<User>>
```

Comment: or you can use something that is _already_ part of the standard library `list.stream().filter(p -> p.getPid() >= 3).collect(toList());`.